# Get multiline substring using regexp

Tags: regex, robotframework

How can I get part of the text using regex?

Text:

```
#first#Cat Dog
Fox
#second#Table Window
#third#Apple Orange
;
```

So I need to get only

```
#first#Cat Dog
Fox
```

I tried:

```
#first#.*
```

But it works only for single line strings

Comment: Please add your programming language / tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems you're looking for a ***tempered greedy token***:

```
^#(?P<key>[^#]+)#(?P<values>(?:(?!^#)[\s\S])+)
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/3KrCeo/1).

Comment: But I know only <key>, for ex: first

Comment: the answer of @jan is really wonderful. For the example you're asking, `^#first#(?P<values>(?:(?!^#)[\s\S])+)` would do the trick (so it's Jan's answer with a concrete 'first' value)

Comment: @malarres: Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`*` matches anything except newlines, but in languages, there are some options (for PHP '/s', for python re.S and re.DOTALL) that make the `*` match the newline too.